# Phonegap - Local storage for JSON

Tags: json, cordova, local-storage

I have followed a tutorial on how to locally store a json feed for offline use (see link below).

http://samcroft.co.uk/2013/using-localstorage-to-store-json/

I implemented the code but unfortunately it didn't work. The json feed is stored but there seems to be a problem retrieving it. I don't have any errors, the feed just doesn't appear.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    cache:  true,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){

        var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('events'));

        $.each(function(key, value){ 

            //do the do

        });

        var localData = JSON.stringify(data);
        window.localStorage.setItem('events', localData);


    },
    error: function(){
        app.showAlert('Something has gone wrong. Please report this issue or check back later.', 'Error');
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('.scroll').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: First, when using localStorage don't put the `window.` before it. Second, why are you getting the `localData` from localStorage? It doesn't look like you're using it anywhere. Have you verified that the JSON object you are receiving from the server is valid? And your `each` function isn't complete, you need to pass it something to iterate through. Last, you are declaring `localData` twice, don't do that.

Comment: This is for phonegap so the 'window.' is required for this to work at all.
As mentioned I followed the tutorial in the link above, the code used is what I was given.